# Recording acoustic guitar with Dynamic and condeser at same time

Tags: microphone, home-studio, microphone-technique, microphone-positioning

It's possible or a bad idea to use a condenser mic and a dynamic mic simultaneously to get body details with the condenser and neck Brightness with the dynamic? There will be seriuos phase issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Record the two mics as two channels. Then you can decide what you want to do when mixing. As this seems to be very uncommon, there probably is a reason. Only way to know for sure is to test it (takes about 15 minutes, so why even ask here? )

Comment: I've done this before, though more often with 2 condensers, one cardioid, the other omni (U87 & B&K 4006), but it doesn't always work, even with the same mics on a different player - as you say, the only way to know what you're going to get is to experiment.

Comment: Thanks ghellquist and Tetsujin! I have posted the question because i didn't bought them already and i was evaluating the different capabilities.

Comment: The "standard" setup ( if you can say anything is standard ) for recording acoustic guitar is one condensor mic. Often a foot or two away from the neck, pointed at 12th fret. Small size condensor, say KM 184 is typical. But then every recording engineer adapts this to taste and guitar and player and room and type of music and role of the guitar ( back- or foreground ) and possibly a lot of other parameters. There simply is no absolutes in recording. In other words, skip the dynamic mic.